How to capture data in Security/Access Control Objects
What's the most efficient way to query these objects: OpportunityShare, GroupMember, PermissionSet, PermissionSetAssignment, ObjectPermissions? I'm also interested in any tools or methods that can streamline this process.

What research have you done, and what have you tried?

@DavidCheng I already tried with scheduled class but its also not working , is there any easy method to monitor that data.

Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to [edit] your post to include your code and include important details like error messages or unexpected results.
